# Wordpress generating PNG thumbnails but not JPG

Tags: wordpress

When adding a new PNG image to the the Media Library in Wordpress (a custom theme), thumbnails are generated correctly. But with JPGs, no thumbnails are generated. Could you please advise me of what the problem might be?

Here's my fuctions.php:

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
add_image_size( 'xxs_size', 100, 100); 
add_image_size( 'xs_size', 100, 100); 
add_image_size( 'sm_size', 300, 300); 
add_image_size( 'md_size', 600, 600 ); 
add_image_size( 'lg_size', 1200, 1200 ); 
add_image_size( 'xl_size', 1920, 1920 );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The underlying problem was the low level server GD library used by Wordpress for generating thumbnails. The particular version of this library was in conflict with the particular PHP version used. Changing of the PHP version helped.

Answer (score 0):

add_image_size should work for all image types irrespective of their extension, untill you use filters such as `wp_handle_upload_prefilter` and modify the core nature.

The easiest way to do this is with a plugin like Regenerate Thumbnails. It will regenerate all of your thumbnails to the new image sizes. install plugin and check if still the problem persists, check your functions related files in your theme.

Comment: Hmm, the Regenerate plugin does not work. I am having a strange error: ERROR: File is not an image.

Comment: OK, the problem was with the server side. Not compliant library versions.

Comment: @MartinS could you post an answer describing how you fixed it?